# Why don't we use other substitute of cement while building a roof for thermal proofing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, heat-transfer

Cement heats up like crazy. I live in the top floor and the heat is unbearable. Also it has a high carbon footprint.

Why still cement is vastly used? When there are so many better alternatives?

Comment: Because it's cheap and easy to do.

Comment: Because reminding architects that other materials exist is difficult, also customers as for cheapest now not most sustainable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as pointed out by others here, it is hard to beat concrete for inexpensive strength and ease of construction. In the dorm building I inhabited in 1970 at the University of California at Davis (a hot place!), the structure was entirely concrete but the roof of the top floor (where I lived) was covered with several inches of insulating foam topped with tar-covered fabric that was painted a light color. The insulation and light color kept the heat out while the concrete underneath it provided the necessary structural strength.

In this way, the advantages of both materials were exploited in combination to produce an inexpensive and strong building that did not get roasted by the sun.